# cURL not work in Flex (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, curl, air

I apologize in advance for the clumsy English)
I have a problem with the launch of cURL in Flex. Here is my code:

```
private var process:NativeProcess;
private var file:File = new File();
private var uploadFile:File = new File();
private var username:String = "user";
private var password:String = "pass";
private var server:String = "ftp:\\--.---.---.---";

public var loadingBar:LoadingBar;

private function startUpload(event:Event):void
{
    loadingBar = LoadingBar(PopUpManager.createPopUp( this, LoadingBar, true));
    loadingBar.progressBar.source = process;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(loadingBar);

    file.nativePath = "C://curl.exe";
    uploadFile.nativePath = "C://001.mov";

    var arguments:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    arguments.push("curl -T " + uploadFile.nativePath + " " + server  + " -u " + username + ":" + password);
    //arguments.push("curl http://isc.sans.org/infocon.txt");
    trace(arguments);

    var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = arguments;
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

    process = new NativeProcess();
    process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onStandardErrorData);
    process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onStandardOutputExit);

    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);

    process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onOutputIOError);
    process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_IO_ERROR, onInputClose);
    process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onStandardIOError);
}
```

standardErrorData issues "% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

```
                       Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0"
and then
"curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl -T C:\001.mov ftp:--.---.---.--- -u user". That is cut off before the colon, which is strange..

And if I use the commented line with the simplest command, instead of the one in before it, I get an error "curl: (1) Protocol curl http not supported or disabled in libcurl".

I do not understand is why so because of the command line the same commands work fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arguments vector is wrong, you should use a separate entry for each argument (unfortunately the [Adobe Live Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcessStartupInfo.html#arguments) are not very clear about how this is supposed to look like), also there's no need to pass `curl` as an argument, the process already knows about the executable.

```
var arguments:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
arguments[0] = '-T';
arguments[1] = uploadFile.nativePath;
arguments[2] = server;
arguments[3] = '-u';
arguments[4] =  username + ':' + password;
```

And make sure that

```
curl -T uploadfile server -u user:passwd
```

is actually the correct format. At least the examples in [the manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) are a little different, they look like

```
curl -T uploadfile -u user:passwd server
```

not sure whether this makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah! It's easier than I thought. You just saved my life)